# java Binary search tree insertion recursion seem to always return null root

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Hi I'm currently trying to build a Java BST with some online references, but I have a problem during my insertion as I realize it does not create a tree after I tried to do inOrder traversal, after some attempts I found issue when passing the root into my insertion method.

My Node class:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    String m_key;
    Object m_value;
    TreeNode m_left;
    TreeNode m_right;
    
    //constructor
    public TreeNode(String inKey, Object inVal)
    {
        if(inKey==null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key cannot be null.");
        }
        
        m_key = inKey;
        m_value = inVal;
        m_left = null;
        m_right = null;
    }
}
```

My insert method:

```
public void insert(String key, Object data)
{
    m_root = insertRec(m_root, key, data);
}

private TreeNode insertRec(TreeNode x, String key, Object val)
{
    if(x == null)
    { 
        x = new TreeNode(key,val);
    }
    
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.m_key);
    if(cmp<0)
    {
        x.m_left = insertRec(x.m_left, key, val);
    }
    else if(cmp>0)
    {
        x.m_right = insertRec(x.m_right, key, val);
    }
    else
    {
        x.m_value = val;
    }
    
    return x;     
}
```

print root:

```
public void printRoot()
{
    System.out.println("the root is: " + m_root.m_key);
}
```

My main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   binaryTree bt = new binaryTree();
   bt.insert("a", "data a");
   bt.insert("b", "data b");
   bt.insert("c", "data c");
   bt.printRoot();
}
```

I got "a" as root result from printing root, and I tried to print root.m_left it shows null. Is there something I could've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive part after the first `if-statement` will always be executed. Also, given it's a BST, if `comp <= 0` recur `left`:

```
if(x == null) { 
  x = new TreeNode(key,val);
} else {  
  int cmp = key.compareTo(x.m_key);
  if(cmp <= 0) {
    x.m_left = insertRec(x.m_left, key, val);
  } else {
    x.m_right = insertRec(x.m_right, key, val);
  }
}
return x;
```

Comment: Really appreciate for replying and pointing out the comparing part, sorry but I don't quite understand what is the difference in the if-statement here, I've tried to replace my code to test out but the output is the same.

Comment: "I tried to print root.m_left it shows null. Is there something I could've missed?" - your root node has key "a", now if you insert node with key "b" it will be inserted as the right child. Similarly for node with key "c", it will be inserted as the right child of node b. Hence no left child exists for node a, that is why you see null while printing root.m_left

Comment: Oh! I get it now, that's very clear and helpful! Thanks!!